# What is the meaning of the R/D flag in ps output?

Tags: linux, process, ps, top

What is the meaning of `R / D` from `ps ax`? Does it indicate a problem?

```
     3 ?        R    522:45 [ksoftirqd/0]
  4380 ?        Rl   1240:31 gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-launch-environment]
  5938 ?        Rs     0:00 ps ax
  6148 ?        Rl   1405:54 gnome-shell --mode=gdm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `ps` manual, under the section "PROCESS STATE CODES":

> ```
>    D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
>    R    running or runnable (on run queue)
>    S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
>    T    stopped by job control signal
>    t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
>    W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
>    X    dead (should never be seen)
>    Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent
> ```

An `R` means that the process is in the run queue.  It does not in any way indicate a problem.

A process in a `D` state will not handle signals straight away as it's currently stuck waiting for disk (usually, and this is where the letter D in the code comes from).  This would indicate an issue if the process is stuck for a longer period of time or if multiple processes are in the same state.  The problem is then probably related to high I/O load (too many processes wanting to read from a too slow disk, for example).

The additional character is also explained:

> For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used,
>       additional characters may be displayed:
>
> ```
>    <    high-priority (not nice to other users)
>    N    low-priority (nice to other users)
>    L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
>    s    is a session leader
>    l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)
>    +    is in the foreground process group
> ```

Related:

- [Why is I/O uninterruptible?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62697/why-is-i-o-uninterruptible)
- [What does the "interruptible sleep" state indicate?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96797/what-does-the-interruptible-sleep-state-indicate)
- [Why "uninterruptible sleep" is not counted as "IDLE"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62693/why-uninterruptible-sleep-is-not-counted-as-idle)
- [Why is uninterruptible sleep indicated by 'D'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267469/why-is-uninterruptible-sleep-indicated-by-d)
- [When a process will go to 'D' state?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16738/when-a-process-will-go-to-d-state)
- (etc.)

Comment: so what from the flags above is indicate about a problem , as I know - D is for sure

Comment: @yael Waiting in uninterruptible sleep does not _need_ to indicate a problem.  If the process is stuck like that for long, or if multiple processes are stuck in the `D` state, then yes maybe.

Comment: I not agree with you see please this case - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/41871

Comment: @yael The link you posted requires a login.  Also, if you are certain, then why ask?  The `D` state is a valid state to be in for a process while waiting for data to be delivered from e.g. disk. There's nothing inherently _bad_ about it. Unless, as I said, it actually gets stuck there, which would indicate an inability of the resource that it's waiting on to deliver data fast enough.

Comment: I update the question with redhat case please see the update

Comment: @yael Yes, that goes in line with what I just said. Also, are you changing the question now? Are you instead asking about processes stuck in `D` state?

Comment: ok I will change the question -